# Deleting rows which contain a day and month but ignore year

Tags: excel, vba

I want to remove rows which are anything before the start of a certain month, so for example anything before the 1st of January needs removing from downloaded SAP data. I was just writing up the code when I thought what about different years?

How do I set it to remove anything less than 01/01 rather then 01/01/2018?

```
Sub Filtration()
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim Front As Worksheet
Dim Iws As Worksheet
Dim Ows As Worksheet
Dim x As Long
Dim Delete As Long
Dim L As String
Dim Answer As Integer
Dim Month As String

Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
Set Front = Wb.Worksheets("Front")
Set Iws = Wb.Worksheets("Input")
Set Ows = Wb.Worksheets("Output")

Iws.Columns("F").Replace What:=".", Replacement:="/", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True

For Delete = Iws.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row To 3 Step -1

With Iws.Cells(Delete, 6)
        If Month = "January" Then
        L = Left(Iws.Cells(Delete, 6), 5)
           If L < "01/01" Then Rows(Delete).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
 End With
Next Delete
```

the above I know is not working, but it hopefully will show you what I am looking to achieve, where the code looks through each row finds that there is a date for lets say 31/12 and remove that row.

Comment: So if the data contains 1/1/2017 you want to keep it, but delete 31/12/2018?

Comment: What I want is any date which is before 01/01/2018 to be removed, however I don't want it to look at the year as that of course is going to change. It should only be the month before in the data so if January remove December, if February remove January dates etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Day](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/day-function) and [Month](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/month-function) functions to test e.g. to remove before 10th April:

```
If Day(Iws.Cells(Delete, 6)) < 10 And Month(Iws.Cells(Delete, 6)) < 4 Then Iws.Rows(Delete).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: Perfect, I knew it would be simple, Just couldn't see it.